# ASP.NET Core, Dependency Injection - Unable To Resolve Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am currently following how the tutorial at [Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and I keep getting the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Infrastructure.Interfaces.IUserRepository' while attempting to activate 'UserManagement.UserTransactions'.

Here is the code that I have implemented so far:

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityWithMongoStores(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionMongoDB"))
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();           

        services.AddScoped<IUserTransactions, UserTransactions>();

        services.AddMvc();  
    }
```

**UserTransactions**

```
public class UserTransactions : IUserTransactions
{        
    public IUserRepository _repository;

    public UserTransactions(IUserRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository; 
    }  

    public void CreateUser(RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        //logic to create user here   
    }
}
```

**IUserTransactions**

```
public interface IUserTransactions
{
    void CreateUser(RegisterModel registerModel);        
}
```

**UserController**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserTransactions _userTransactions; 

    public UserController(IUserTransactions userTransactions)
    {
        _userTransactions = userTransactions;
    }

    [HttpGet]        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult CreateUser(RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        _userTransactions.CreateUser(registerModel);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

I am currently using .NET Core 2.0.

Lastly, I know this question is similar to others posted here but they did not provide the answers I needed.

Comment: You register `IUserTransactions` but not `IUserRepository`. It can't resolve `UserRepository` because none is registered, make sure you have that implemented and registered.

Comment: @JSteward : I have been staring at this for too long. Thanks for pointing that out, its working now